# How to drop pandas default index column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

After processing my files and write the output to an excel/csv, I get an extra column with some numbers. How can i omit it when writing my final output?

```
 df.to_excel(writer, columns=['Document Date', 'Site',..], sheet_name='summary')
```

In the attached picture very first column without column name. (this column causes issue in the process. means I cannot keep any unknown column in my sheet)

[image]

Comment: Try `df.to_excel(..., index=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `index=False`. See [DataFrame.to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

```py
df.to_excel(writer, columns=['Document Date', 'Site',..], sheet_name='summary', index=False)
```